# Laravel 7 - Login with Apple causes session to be overwritten several times

Tags: php, laravel

In essence, I'm working on an application that allows users to login from multiple providers: Facebook, Twitter and Apple.
When user visits a route that's guarded by auth, he is then redirected to a login screen. At that point I save the intended route by doing the following in the RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:

```
...
$url = redirect()->intended()->getTargetUrl();
if(!Session::has('redirect') || (Session::get('redirect') === 'https://example.com')) {
   Session::put('redirect', $url);
}
...
```

I've also tried the following approach:

```
...
$url = redirect()->intended()->getTargetUrl();
if((!Session::has('redirect') || Session::get('redirect') === 'https://example.com') && $url !== 'https://example.com') {
    Session::put('redirect', $url);
}
...
```

However, this causes the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in ../framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php on line 65
```

And Line 65 of the error above is:

```
return $next($request);
```

As you can see I save the intended URL to the session which works fine for GET requests for providers like Facebook and Twitter, however, since Apple requires POST request with the data, I've noticed that my session is overwritten several times by looking at the Log output e.g.

```
[2020-07-28 17:53:02] debug.INFO: URL: ($url) https://example.com <-- Incorrect Value
[2020-07-28 17:53:05] debug.INFO: URL: ($url) https://example.com/redirect?route_params <-- Correct Value
[2020-07-28 17:53:07] debug.INFO: URL: ($url) https://example.com <-- Incorrect Value
```

I've tried to handle this by Cookies and Locking Cache but to no avail. Am I doing something wrong with the way I handle the sessions and/or redirects?

Best, J.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way that Apple sign in works, the session is getting wiped before the user is logged in. So the redirect can't work with session.

I solved it using cookies.

On the initial request I would grab the intended url, and store it in a cookie, making sure you set the lifespan, so that it doesn't get wiped alongside the session.

```
$url = redirect()->intended()->getTargetUrl();
$urlBase = url()->to('/');

if(($url != $urlBase) && ($url != $urlBase . '/login') && (substr($url, 0, strlen($urlBase)) === $urlBase)) {
    Cookie::queue('redirect', $url, 1);
}
```

Then let the whole authentication lifecycle complete, let it redirect to you home route.
In the controller method for said route, I check if the cookie exists, and if it does I redirect the user to that url.

```
if (Cookie::has('redirect')) {
    redirect = Cookie::get('redirect');
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('redirect'));

    return redirect($redirect);
}
```

It might not be the most elegant way of doing this, but it works with all the providers you mentioned.